# How can I split a string by whitespace unless inside of a single quoted string?

Tags: regex, perl, split

I'm seeking a solution to splitting a string which contains text in the following format:

```
"abcd efgh 'ijklm no pqrs' tuv"
```

which will produce the following results:

```
['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijklm no pqrs', 'tuv']
```

In other words, it splits by whitespace unless inside of a single quoted string.  I think it could be done with .NET regexps using "Lookaround" operators, particularly balancing operators. I'm not so sure about Perl.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [Text::ParseWords](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::ParseWords):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;

my @words = parse_line('\s+', 0, "abcd efgh 'ijklm no pqrs' tuv");

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@words;
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> ff
$VAR1 = [
          'abcd',
          'efgh',
          'ijklm no pqrs',
          'tuv'
        ];
```

You can look at the source code for `Text::ParseWords::parse_line` to see the pattern used.

Comment: @Jergason blame it on the wonderful people who, when they *don't* find exactly what they need, and have to write it themselves, CPAN the result afterwards. :)

Comment: @zan FWIW, `Text::ParseWords` is in the core. Also, modules or distributions with giant dependency lists are not that common.

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $text = "abcd efgh 'ijklm no pqrs' tuv 'xwyz 1234 9999' 'blah'";
my @out;

my @parts = split /'/, $text;

for ( my $i = 1; $i < $#parts; $i += 2 ) {
    push @out, split( /\s+/, $parts[$i - 1] ), $parts[$i];
}

push @out, $parts[-1];

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@out;
```

Comment: You should explain the program a bit.

Answer (score 1):

So you've decided to use a regex? Now you have two problems.

Allow me to infer a little bit. You want an arbitrary number of fields, where a field is composed of text without containing a space, or it is separated by spaces and begins with a quote and ends with a quote (possibly with spaces inbetween).

In other words, you want to do what a command line shell does. You really should just reuse something. Failing that, you should capture a field at a time, with a regex something like:

```
^ *([^ ]+|'[^']*')(.*)
```

Where you append group one to your list, and continue the loop with the contents of group 2.

A single pass through a regex wouldn't be able to capture an arbitrarily large number of fields. You might be able to split on a regex (python will do this, not sure about perl), but since you are matching the stuff outside the spaces, I'm not sure that is even an option.